# Remotely manage child's computer

Tags: windows, remote-access

I'm looking for a program that will allow controlling when a child can use their computer when I am not home. I want to be able to set a basic schedule, but be able to modify it remotely. I haven't found a program yet that can do this, is there one?

Comment: Which OS is the childs computer or are you open to a change of OS?

Comment: What do you need to be "managed"? The entire system/login, the use of certain programs, or use of network, or the use of certain websites only, or... what?

Comment: The term to search for is [parental control software](https://www.google.com/search?q=parental+control+software)

Comment: Related: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13710/6834

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use **[Ammyy Admin](http://www.ammyy.com/en/admin_parental_control.html)** as free parental control & monitoring software.

> - You can connect to any PC within a few seconds.
> - You can view desktop of a remote computer from any PC connected to
>     the Internet without tedious configuration, registration and
>     installation.
> - Ammyy Admin works with all known firewalls and antiviens software
>     (unlike spyware which can be easily detected as malicious
>     application). Properly configured Ammyy Admin is almost impossible to
>     detect.
> - Your child will never find out that you watch all his actions at PC
>     in real time.
> - You can instantly turn on voice chat feature and listen to what is
>     happening on the other side.

**Best feature!**

***Ammyy Admin is absolutely free for home use provided you don't exceed time limit of free version.***

**Free version is used for home and might be limited if used beyond 15 hours per month per computer*. Number of simultaneous outgoing/incoming connections - 2/1.**

[image]